# How to override view via themes? (yii2)

Tags: php, view, yii, yii2

I need to override a view file like ‘pathMap’ => [ ‘@dektrium/user/views’ => ‘@app/views/site’] I followed manual (https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/docs/overriding-views.md) but all I see is the old view whatever I do. Perhaps something wrong with baseUrl or basePath but I’m not sure what I should do.

frontend/config/main.php:

```
'components' => [
'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
            'baseUrl' => '/',
        ],
// .................
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '/' => 'site/index',
                '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
            ],
        ],
'view' => [
       'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'theme' => [
                //'basePath' => '@app/themes/basic',
                //'baseUrl' => '@app/views/site',
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@dektrium/user/views' => '@app/views/site'
                ]
            ]
        ]
//.................
]
```

common/config/main.php:

```
'modules' => [
'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'admins' => ['admin'],
            'modelMap' => [
                'User' => 'common\models\User',
            ],
]
```

I open page on the address like mydomain.test/user/register (in case it’s somehow matter)
I also tried to put ‘view’ part in components of common/config/main.php and of module. Tried to create themes folder and put new view therein, nothing seems work

Answer (score 0):

ok, I finally fixed it

```
'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'theme' => [
                'basePath' => '@frontend/views/site',
                'baseUrl' => '@frontend/views/site',
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@dektrium/user/views/registration' => '@frontend/views/site',
                ]
            ]
        ]
```